# Фразеологизмы разных стилей

Tags: фразеология

Назовите, пожалуйста, фразеологизмы публицистического, художественного, научного, официально-делового стилей. Заранее спасибо. )

Answer (score 2):

Публицистического - святая святых, исчадие ада, по образу и подобию, глас вопиющего в пустыне, земля обетованная, дамоклов меч, прометеев огонь, танталовы муки, калиф на час, на поле брани, одержать победу, святее святых, ум честь и совесть нашей эпохи и другие.

Художественного - закусить удила, бить ключом, очертя голову, товарищ по несчастью, плакать в жилетку, телячий восторг и другие.

Научного - каменный уголь, английская булавка, глазное яблоко, tabula rasa (лат. чистая доска; нечто нетронутое, абсолютно чистое).

Официально-делового - повестка дня, силовые ведомства, материальные ценности, продукты питания, транспортные средства, дипломатические отношения, бюджетная сфера, единовременное пособие, кассационная жалоба, дать указания (указать), оказать содействие (воздействовать), приводит к усложнению (усложняет), иметь значение и др.

Answer (score 0):

Публицистического - сизифов труд, прокрустово ложе, троянский конь, крокодиловы слёзы, юмор висельников.

Художественного - дать дуба, задавать тон, валять дурака.

Научного - горизонт событий, задача трёх тел, кусочно-гладкая функция.

Официально-делового - верительные грамоты, автокефальная церковь, военно-морские силы.